# Finding p value matlab

Tags: statistics, matlab

Wondering how to solve the following problem with matlab. Tried applying ttest and ttest 2 to the data but answer is not correct. Can't figure out why. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Microbial activity was measured on 32 samples, giving the following measurements (in mg per sample)

[229, 250, 202, 251, 287, 193, 294, 221, 219, 245, 291, 258, 180, 163, 162, 224, 245, 161, 226, 160, 250, 219, 237, 199, 260, 295, 196, 200, 178, 181, 236, 152]

Then a lime treatment was applied to each of the 32 samples (to balance soil pH), and microbial activity was measured again on the same 32 samples, giving the following measurements (in mg per sample):

[226, 250, 221, 267, 304, 205, 313, 236, 206, 254, 284, 259, 179, 164, 169, 215, 264, 166, 233, 170, 270, 215, 238, 186, 274, 297, 187, 198, 194, 169, 254, 137]

Use Matlab to test for evidence that the lime treatment increased microbial activity, at the 0.1 significance level.

Find a P-value for this test (to 3 decimal places)

Comment: Considering that the lime treatment is applied on the same 32 samples, you need a paired t-test. Did you do that?

Comment: Would be a stronger question if you showed results you obtained along with the 'correct' answer you were given. Then it might have been possible to discuss where your analysis went wrong. // Wrongly treating this as a two-sample t test gives p-val about .7 (two-sided) and about .35 (one-sided). [Bogus results with Welch and pooled 2-sample tests have about the same p-values.]

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to Matlab, so I can't help you with syntax for that
package.

**P-value of one-sided paired t test.**

However, assuming data are nearly normal, I agree with the comment by @Raskolnikov that you need
a paired t test test. Specifically, a paired test of $H_0: \mu_a - \mu_b = \mu_D = 0$
against the one-sided alternative $H_a: \mu_D > 0.$ Results from R statistical
software (slightly edited for relevance) are as follows:

```
x.a = c(226, 250, 221, 267, 304, 205, 313, 236, 206, 254, 284, 259, 
        179, 164, 169, 215, 264, 166, 233, 170, 270, 215, 238, 186, 
        274, 297, 187, 198, 194, 169, 254, 137)
x.b = c(229, 250, 202, 251, 287, 193, 294, 221, 219, 245, 291, 258, 
        180, 163, 162, 224, 245, 161, 226, 160, 250, 219, 237, 199, 
        260, 295, 196, 200, 178, 181, 236, 152)
d = x.a-x.b
t.test(d, alte="gr")

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 2.2296, df = 31, p-value = 0.01658
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0
sample estimates:
mean of d 
    4.375
```

So the p-value is 0.01658. The test statistic is 
$T = \frac{\bar D - 0}{S_D/\sqrt{32}} = 2.2296,$ and
the (one-sided) p-value 0.01658 is the probability to the right of $T$
under the density curve of Student's t distribution with 31
degrees of freedom. Intermediate computations:

```
mean(d);  sd(d)
## 4.375      # sample mean of differences
## 11.09999   # sample SD of differences

mean(d)/(sd(d)/sqrt(32))
## 2.229619   # test statistic

1 - pt(2.2296, 31)
## 0.01657741 # p-value
```

Because the p-value exceeds 1%, you cannot reject $H_0$ to conclude
that the lime treatment increases microbial activity. (However, you could
have rejected at the 5% level.)

In the figure below, the p-value is the area under the curve to the
right of the vertical broken line.

[image]

*Notes:* (1) There is some indication that the differences may not be normal.
They barely fail a Shapiro-Wilk test (p-value $\approx 0.05)$ and a normal probability plot reveals
that the sample is more short-tailed than normal. Even so, for a sample size as large as $n = 32,$
the t test should be reliable.

(2) The traditional alternative to a t test, a Wilcoxon signed-rank test runs into 
some difficulty because of tied observations among the differences. But
its one-sided p-value is approximately $0.02 > 0.01,$ so it does not reject the
null hypothesis (1% level) that the *median* difference is greater than 0.

(3) A one-sided simulated permutation test on paired differences gives p-value about 0.17, essentially the same as the paired t test.

Answer (score 1):

With MATLAB

```
a = [229 250 202 251 287 193 294 221 219 245 291 258
     180 163 162 224 245 161 226 160 250 219 237 199
     260 295 196 200 178 181 236 152];

b = [226 250 221 267 304 205 313 236 206 254 284 259
     179 164 169 215 264 166 233 170 270 215 238 186
     274 297 187 198 194 169 254 137];

[~,p] = ttest(a,b,'Tail','left')

p =

    0.0166
```

---

For comparison, using R and Stata

With R

```
a <- c(229, 250, 202, 251, 287, 193, 294, 221, 219, 245, 291, 258,
       180, 163, 162, 224, 245, 161, 226, 160, 250, 219, 237, 199,
       260, 295, 196, 200, 178, 181, 236, 152)

b <- c(226, 250, 221, 267, 304, 205, 313, 236, 206, 254, 284, 259,
       179, 164, 169, 215, 264, 166, 233, 170, 270, 215, 238, 186,
       274, 297, 187, 198, 194, 169, 254, 137)

t.test(a, b, paired=T, alternative="less")

    Paired t-test

data:  a and b
t = -2.2296, df = 31, p-value = 0.01658
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
      -Inf -1.048021
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                 -4.375
```

With Stata

```
mat a=229,226\250,250\202,221\251,267\287,304\193,205\294,313\ ///
      221,236\219,206\245,254\291,284\258,259\180,179\163,164\ ///
      162,169\224,215\245,264\161,166\226,233\160,170\250,270\ ///
      219,215\237,238\199,186\260,274\295,297\196,187\200,198\ ///
      178,194\181,169\236,254\152,137
svmat a
ren * (a b)
ttest a==b

Paired t test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. Err.   Std. Dev.   [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
       a |      32      220.75    7.379543      41.745    205.6993    235.8007
       b |      32     225.125    8.167198    46.20065    208.4679    241.7821
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |      32      -4.375    1.962219    11.09999   -8.376972   -.3730285
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     mean(diff) = mean(a - b)                                     t =  -2.2296
 Ho: mean(diff) = 0                              degrees of freedom =       31

 Ha: mean(diff) < 0           Ha: mean(diff) != 0           Ha: mean(diff) > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.0166         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0332          Pr(T > t) = 0.9834
```

Comment: Interesting to compare printouts from different software packages. (+1)